# Anorm missing or invalid dependency detected while loading class file 'JavaTimeColumn.class'

Tags: scala, anorm

file src/main/scala/Test.scala:

```
import anorm.SQL
import anorm.SqlParser.{str, float}
import anorm._

object Test {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val dbUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test"
    Class.forName("org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver").newInstance()
    implicit val conn: java.sql.Connection = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl)

    val parser = str("name") ~ float("weight") map { case name ~ f => (name -> f) }
    val result = SQL("select name, weight from products").as(parser.single)
  }
}
```

file build.sbt:

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

libraryDependencies += "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.38"

libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" %% "anorm" % "2.5.0"
```

run it:

```
$ sbt sbt-version
[info] Set current project to test (in build file:/home/david/test/)
[info] 0.13.11

$ sbt run
[info] Set current project to test (in build file:/home/david/test/)
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /home/david/test/target/scala-2.11/classes...
[error] missing or invalid dependency detected while loading class file 'JavaTimeColumn.class'.
[error] Could not access type ZonedDateTime in value java.time,
[error] because it (or its dependencies) are missing. Check your build definition for
[error] missing or conflicting dependencies. (Re-run with `-Ylog-classpath` to see the problematic classpath.)
[error] A full rebuild may help if 'JavaTimeColumn.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of java.time.
[error]                                                                ^
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
```

I've tried everything from scratch: a new ubuntu virtual machine, installed sbt and run this (so, no previous .m2, .sbt nor .ivy directories).

Comment: What version of java are you running this with ?

Comment: Indicate the java and anorm versions

Comment: java version 1.7.0 (1.7.0_65 on `ubuntu /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre`, and 1.7.0_40 `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home/jre` on OSX).
anorm version 2.5.0, as you can see in build.sbt.

Comment: I have Installed Java 1.8.0_77, and now I get a more clear error. It does mention anything about missing dependency, now the one error shown is `not found: value ~`

Comment: so I've added `import anorm._` and now it compiles and runs successfully on JDK 1.8.0. It does still not compile in JDK 1.7.0 though. So, the question now is why it does not work on JDK 1.7.0?
(I've updated the question accordingly)

Comment: ok, anorm >=2.4.0 requires Java 8 as explained in their website: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/Anorm
wouldn't it be possible for a library to state this requirement, so that the compiler can show a useful error message instead of such as misleading one?

Comment: @dragisa-krsmanovic, you were the first to inquiry about java version, which lead me to the solution. please write an answer saying that anorm >=2.4.0 requires Java 8, and I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Play 2.4 requires Java 8. So my guess was that Play Anorm expects Java 8 too. The error indicates that it's trying to use `java.util.time` which was added in Java 8.